# OleDb unhandled exception while querying List<T>

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

If I run the below query on directly on SQL Database, it works

```
var result =
    from log in db.DeviceLogs
    let byId = 
        db.DeviceLogs.Where(item => item.UserId == log.UserId)
    let first =
        byId.First(item => item.LogDate == byId.Min(min => min.LogDate))
    where 
        log.Equals(first) || (log.LogDate - first.LogDate).Minutes > 5
    select log;
```

But if I run against filtered List it fails with `OleDb Exception`

```
var filteredDeviceLogs = db.DeviceLogs
                        .Where(s => s.LogDate.Value.Date >= StartDate.Date  
                                   && s.LogDate.Value.Date < EndDate.AddDays(1));

 var result =
        from log in filteredDeviceLogs 
        let byId = 
            db.DeviceLogs.Where(item => item.UserId == log.UserId)
        let first =
            byId.First(item => item.LogDate == byId.Min(min => min.LogDate))
        where 
            log.Equals(first) || (log.LogDate - first.LogDate).Minutes > 5
        select log;

bool status = result.Any();    //OleDb Unhandled Exception
```

**Exception Detail:**
`Unrecognized keyword WHEN.`

**Stack Trace**

```
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
```

**I assume this may be cause of CASE WHEN STATEMENT used in conversion, but if I copy the query, there is no CASE WHEN statements**

**Linq Query**

```
SELECT [t0].[DeviceLogId], [t0].[DownloadDate], [t0].[DeviceId], [t0].[UserId], [t0].[LogDate], [t0].[Direction], [t0].[AttDirection], [t0].[C1], [t0].[C2], [t0].[C3], [t0].[C4], [t0].[C5], [t0].[C6], [t0].[C7], [t0].[WorkCode]
FROM [DeviceLogs] AS [t0]
WHERE ((EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t1].[DeviceLogId]
        FROM [DeviceLogs] AS [t1]
        WHERE ([t1].[LogDate] = ((
            SELECT MIN([t2].[LogDate])
            FROM [DeviceLogs] AS [t2]
            WHERE [t2].[UserId] = [t0].[UserId]
            ))) AND ([t1].[UserId] = [t0].[UserId])
        ) AS [t3]
    WHERE [t0].[DeviceLogId] = [t3].[DeviceLogId]
    )) OR ((CONVERT(Int,(CONVERT(BigInt,(CONVERT(BigInt,(((CONVERT(BigInt,DATEDIFF(DAY, (
    SELECT [t12].[LogDate]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t10].[LogDate]
        FROM [DeviceLogs] AS [t10]
        WHERE ([t10].[LogDate] = ((
            SELECT MIN([t11].[LogDate])
            FROM [DeviceLogs] AS [t11]
            WHERE [t11].[UserId] = [t0].[UserId]
            ))) AND ([t10].[UserId] = [t0].[UserId])
        ) AS [t12]
    ), [t0].[LogDate]))) * 86400000) + DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, (
    SELECT [t12].[LogDate]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t10].[LogDate]
        FROM [DeviceLogs] AS [t10]
        WHERE ([t10].[LogDate] = ((
            SELECT MIN([t11].[LogDate])
            FROM [DeviceLogs] AS [t11]
            WHERE [t11].[UserId] = [t0].[UserId]
            ))) AND ([t10].[UserId] = [t0].[UserId])
        ) AS [t12]
    ), [t0].[LogDate]), (
    SELECT [t12].[LogDate]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t10].[LogDate]
        FROM [DeviceLogs] AS [t10]
        WHERE ([t10].[LogDate] = ((
            SELECT MIN([t11].[LogDate])
            FROM [DeviceLogs] AS [t11]
            WHERE [t11].[UserId] = [t0].[UserId]
            ))) AND ([t10].[UserId] = [t0].[UserId])
        ) AS [t12]
    )), [t0].[LogDate])) * 10000)) / 600000000)) % 60)) > @p0)) AND (CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[LogDate]) >= @p1) AND (CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[LogDate]) < @p2)
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that whichever data source you are accessing via OLEDB does not support case statements.

The Linq query is being translated into SQL which includes a `WHEN` keyword (presumably as part of a `CASE` statement) but OLEDB can be used to wrap all kinds of data sources and not all of them will support such constructions.

If you are accessing a SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, or other major database system then you should use the appropriate ADO.NET provider for that system instead of OLEDB. If you're accessing some other data source, e.g. Excel, then you may be out of luck. If you can find out what SQL is being issued to the data source then that may provide more information for solving this problem.

Comment: I too assumed the same, but when I looked at the SQL query part of the linq statement, there is absolutely no CASE WHEN statements !!

Comment: Could the OLEDB provider be doing some further translating and modifying the SQL, to include a CASE statement? Which database/data source are you accessing?

Comment: I am accessing MS Access Database with `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` driver